# Doctrine 2 perform insert, update on entity locally but fails without error on staging

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have an entity called DoerTrip

```
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Doer Trip
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="doer_trip")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class DoerTrip extends AbstractEntity
{
const STATUS_PUBLISHED = 1;
const STATUS_UNPUBLISHED = 0;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`id`", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\Doer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="`doer_id`", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $doer; // inversedBy="trips"

/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\Trip
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Trip")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="`trip_id`", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $trip; //inversedBy="doers"

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`published`", type="boolean")
 */
protected $published;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`comment`", type="text")
 */
protected $comment;


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`target_sum`", type="integer")
 */
protected $targetSum;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->published = false;
}
/**
 * @param string $comment
 * @return $this
 */
public function setComment($comment)
{
    $this->comment = $comment;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getComment()
{
    return $this->comment;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\Doer $doer
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDoer(Doer $doer)
{
    $this->doer = $doer;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Application\Entity\Doer
 */
public function getDoer()
{
    return $this->doer;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 * @return $this
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param boolean $published
 * @return $this
 */
public function setPublished($published)
{
    $this->published = $published;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getPublished()
{
    return $this->published;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\Trip $trip
 * @return $this
 */
public function setTrip(Trip $trip)
{
    $this->trip = $trip;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Application\Entity\Trip
 */
public function getTrip()
{
    return $this->trip;
}

/**
 * @param int $targetSum
 * @return $this
 */
public function setTargetSum($targetSum)
{
    $this->targetSum = $targetSum;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getTargetSum()
{
    return (null !== $this->targetSum) ? $this->targetSum : $this->getTrip()->getTargetAmount();
}
}
```

here Trip Entity:

```
 namespace Application\Entity;

 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Zend\Validator\IsInstanceOf;

 /**
  * Trip
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="trip")
  * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Trip extends AbstractEntity
 {
  const STATUS_ACTIVE = 'active';
  const STATUS_INACTIVE = 'inactive';
  const STATUS_BANNED = 'banned';

  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $name;
/**
 * @var Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Media", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="trip_media",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="trip_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 * )
 */
protected $media;

/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\Media
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Media", mappedBy="trip", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="main_media_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $mainMedia;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="api_key", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $apiKey;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $country;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="departure_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $departureDate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="due_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $dueDate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="return_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $returnDate;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
protected $description;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="target_amount", type="integer")
 */
protected $targetAmount;

/**
 * @var Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DoerTrip", mappedBy="trip", cascade={"persist","remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $doers;

/**
 * @var Organization
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organization", inversedBy="trips")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $organization;

/**
 * @var Cause
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Cause", inversedBy="trips")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cause_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $cause;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string" ,columnDefinition="ENUM('active', 'inactive', 'banned')")
 */
protected $status;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;



/**
 * @var Transaction
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Transaction", mappedBy="trip", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $transactions;

/**
 * @param Organization $organization
 * @return $this
 */
public function setOrganization(Organization $organization)
{
    $this->organization = $organization;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Organization
 */
public function getOrganization()
{
    return $this->organization;
}


public function __construct()
{
    $this->doers = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->media = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
    $this->transactions = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->targetAmount = 0;
    $this->description = '';
}

/**
 * @param string $apiKey
 * @return $this
 */
public function setApiKey($apiKey)
{
    $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getApiKey()
{
    return $this->apiKey;
}

/**
 * @param string $country
 * @return $this
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->country = $country;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->country;
}

/**
 * @param string $description
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $dueDate
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDueDate(\DateTime $dueDate)
{
    $this->dueDate = $dueDate;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDueDate()
{
    return $this->dueDate;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 * @return $this
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $departureDate
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDepartureDate(\DateTime $departureDate)
{
    $this->departureDate = $departureDate;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDepartureDate()
{
    return $this->departureDate;
}

/**
 * @param string $targetAmount
 * @return $this
 */
public function setTargetAmount($targetAmount)
{
    $this->targetAmount = $targetAmount;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getTargetAmount()
{
    return $this->targetAmount;
}

/**
 * @param string $name
 * @return $this
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @param int $status
 * @return $this
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\Cause $cause
 * @return $this
 */
public function setCause($cause)
{
    $this->cause = $cause;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Application\Entity\Cause
 */
public function getCause()
{
    return $this->cause;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $media
 * @return $this
 */
public function setMedia($media)
{
    $this->media = $media;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getMedia()
{
    return $this->media;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\DoerTrip $doer
 * @return $this
 */
public function addDoer(DoerTrip $doer)
{
    $this->doers->add($doer);
    $doer->setTrip($this);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param Collection $doers
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDoers(Collection $doers)
{
    $this->doers = $doers;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getDoers()
{
    return $this->doers;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\DoerTrip $doer
 * @return $this
 */
public function removeDoer(DoerTrip $doer)
{
    $this->doers->removeElement($doer);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $transactions
 * @return $this
 */
public function setTransactions($transactions)
{
    $this->transactions = $transactions;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getTransactions()
{
    return $this->transactions;
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return $this
 */
public function populate(array $data)
{
    if (!empty($data['departureDate']) && !$data['departureDate'] instanceof \DateTime) {
        $data['departureDate'] = new \DateTime($data['departureDate']);
    }
    if (!empty($data['dueDate']) && !$data['dueDate'] instanceof \DateTime) {
        $data['dueDate'] = new \DateTime($data['dueDate']);
    }

    if (!empty($data['returnDate']) && !$data['returnDate'] instanceof \DateTime) {
        $data['returnDate'] = new \DateTime($data['returnDate']);
    }
    parent::populate($data);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $returnDate
 * @return $this
 */
public function setReturnDate(\DateTime $returnDate)
{
    $this->returnDate = $returnDate;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getReturnDate()
{
    return $this->returnDate;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\Media $mainMedia
 * @return $this
 */
public function setMainMedia($mainMedia)
{
    $this->mainMedia = $mainMedia;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Application\Entity\Media
 */
public function getMainMedia()
{
    return $this->mainMedia;
}


/**
 * @param Media $media
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasMedia(Media $media)
{
    return $this->getMedia()->contains($media);
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\Media $media
 * @return $this
 */
public function addMedia(Media $media)
{
    $this->media->add($media);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\Media $media
 * @return $this
 */
public function removeMedia(Media $media)
{
    $this->media->removeElement($media);
    return $this;
}


}
```

Here is Doer Entity

```
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Validator\IsInstanceOf;

/**
 * Trip
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="trip")
 * @ORM\Entity
*/
class Trip extends AbstractEntity
{
const STATUS_ACTIVE = 'active';
const STATUS_INACTIVE = 'inactive';
const STATUS_BANNED = 'banned';

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $name;
/**
 * @var Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Media", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="trip_media",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="trip_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 * )
 */
protected $media;

/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\Media
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Media", mappedBy="trip", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="main_media_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $mainMedia;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="api_key", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $apiKey;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $country;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="departure_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $departureDate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="due_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $dueDate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="return_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $returnDate;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
protected $description;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="target_amount", type="integer")
 */
protected $targetAmount;

/**
 * @var Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DoerTrip", mappedBy="trip", cascade={"persist","remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $doers;

/**
 * @var Organization
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organization", inversedBy="trips")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $organization;

/**
 * @var Cause
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Cause", inversedBy="trips")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cause_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $cause;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string" ,columnDefinition="ENUM('active', 'inactive', 'banned')")
 */
protected $status;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;



/**
 * @var Transaction
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Transaction", mappedBy="trip", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $transactions;

/**
 * @param Organization $organization
 * @return $this
 */
public function setOrganization(Organization $organization)
{
    $this->organization = $organization;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Organization
 */
public function getOrganization()
{
    return $this->organization;
}


public function __construct()
{
    $this->doers = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->media = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
    $this->transactions = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->targetAmount = 0;
    $this->description = '';
}

/**
 * @param string $apiKey
 * @return $this
 */
public function setApiKey($apiKey)
{
    $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getApiKey()
{
    return $this->apiKey;
}

/**
 * @param string $country
 * @return $this
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->country = $country;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->country;
}

/**
 * @param string $description
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $dueDate
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDueDate(\DateTime $dueDate)
{
    $this->dueDate = $dueDate;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDueDate()
{
    return $this->dueDate;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 * @return $this
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $departureDate
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDepartureDate(\DateTime $departureDate)
{
    $this->departureDate = $departureDate;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDepartureDate()
{
    return $this->departureDate;
}

/**
 * @param string $targetAmount
 * @return $this
 */
public function setTargetAmount($targetAmount)
{
    $this->targetAmount = $targetAmount;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getTargetAmount()
{
    return $this->targetAmount;
}

/**
 * @param string $name
 * @return $this
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @param int $status
 * @return $this
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\Cause $cause
 * @return $this
 */
public function setCause($cause)
{
    $this->cause = $cause;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Application\Entity\Cause
 */
public function getCause()
{
    return $this->cause;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $media
 * @return $this
 */
public function setMedia($media)
{
    $this->media = $media;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getMedia()
{
    return $this->media;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\DoerTrip $doer
 * @return $this
 */
public function addDoer(DoerTrip $doer)
{
    $this->doers->add($doer);
    $doer->setTrip($this);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param Collection $doers
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDoers(Collection $doers)
{
    $this->doers = $doers;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getDoers()
{
    return $this->doers;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\DoerTrip $doer
 * @return $this
 */
public function removeDoer(DoerTrip $doer)
{
    $this->doers->removeElement($doer);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $transactions
 * @return $this
 */
public function setTransactions($transactions)
{
    $this->transactions = $transactions;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getTransactions()
{
    return $this->transactions;
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return $this
 */
public function populate(array $data)
{
    if (!empty($data['departureDate']) && !$data['departureDate'] instanceof \DateTime) {
        $data['departureDate'] = new \DateTime($data['departureDate']);
    }
    if (!empty($data['dueDate']) && !$data['dueDate'] instanceof \DateTime) {
        $data['dueDate'] = new \DateTime($data['dueDate']);
    }

    if (!empty($data['returnDate']) && !$data['returnDate'] instanceof \DateTime) {
        $data['returnDate'] = new \DateTime($data['returnDate']);
    }
    parent::populate($data);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $returnDate
 * @return $this
 */
public function setReturnDate(\DateTime $returnDate)
{
    $this->returnDate = $returnDate;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getReturnDate()
{
    return $this->returnDate;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\Media $mainMedia
 * @return $this
 */
public function setMainMedia($mainMedia)
{
    $this->mainMedia = $mainMedia;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \Application\Entity\Media
 */
public function getMainMedia()
{
    return $this->mainMedia;
}


/**
 * @param Media $media
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasMedia(Media $media)
{
    return $this->getMedia()->contains($media);
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\Media $media
 * @return $this
 */
public function addMedia(Media $media)
{
    $this->media->add($media);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param \Application\Entity\Media $media
 * @return $this
 */
public function removeMedia(Media $media)
{
    $this->media->removeElement($media);
    return $this;
}
}
```

I perform this sample of code:

```
 $doerTrip = new DoerTrip();
 $doerTrip->setDoer($doer)->setTrip($trip);
 $em->persist($doerTrip);
 $em->flush();
```

locally it works (on Windows). But on staging (Ubuntu) new record is not created and I don't get any errors. Update of the entity DoerTrip on staging doesn't work too.

If I perform insert with the  help of connection something like this

```
     $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO doer_trip (...) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');
     $stmt->bindParam(1, $param);
      ...
```

everything works fine.
When using ORM in SQL Logger I can see

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO doer_trip (...) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
COMMIT;
```

but new record is not created on staging.
locally everything works fine.

I don't know maybe it depends on MySQL configuration.

I have no idea.

Here my doer_trip table

```
CREATE TABLE `doer_trip` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`doer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`trip_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`published` INT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`comment` TEXT NULL,
`target_sum` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `doer_id` (`doer_id`),
INDEX `trip_id` (`trip_id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `doer_iduniq` (`doer_id`, `trip_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_doer_trip_trip` FOREIGN KEY (`trip_id`) REFERENCES `trip` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_doer_trip_doer` FOREIGN KEY (`doer_id`) REFERENCES `doer` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
AUTO_INCREMENT=41
```

Comment: I had a problem in the past, depending on the OS. Windows is not case sensitive, Ubuntu (Unix) it is. **Try to enable debug at staging and check if the entities are well built.** My problem was that I had my cached entity bad built because inside a relationship I had something like "myEntity", but actually was "MyEntity", so it failed. Check that, just in case ;)

Comment: run `doctrine orm:validate-schema` on staging

Comment: I ran doctrine orm:validate-schema. All mappings are correct. But the same behavior

Comment: I investigate mysql log of staging for this table doer_trip there is no execute of INSERT query.
`START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)`
But there is no execute of prepared statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in

```
/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`published`", type="boolean")
 */
protected $published;
```

If I set type to integer like this

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`published`", type="integer")
 */
protected $published;
```

Everything work fine. But why it works fine on my local environment???